# Dating photograph of car, man and dog from perhaps 1930s/40s in Texas (or perhaps Missouri)?

Tags: photo-identification, photo-dating, texas, missouri

I have a picture of a man with his dog in a car and I'm trying to approximate the date of the picture to help figure out which relative is in the picture.  I'm thinking it is from the 1920s or 1930s and that the picture may be taken in the 1930s or 1940s.  What clues can we get from the man's clothing, dashboard of the car, seat, and the door mechanisms?  The photo is likely taken in either Texas (more likely) or Missouri.  I have a second photo dated 1942 from Kansas City, Missouri that **might** show the front of the same car and another showing possibly the back in Fort Worth dated around 1926-31.

[image: Man with dog in his lap seen sitting in driver seat of car with open door]
[image: Snippet of front of possibly same car in photo dated September 23, 1942 from Kansas City, Missouri]
[image: Snippet of back of possibly same car in photo from 1926 to 1931 taken in Fort Worth, Texas]

Comment: You could try asking on Motor Vehicle.SE.  There is a "vehicle-identification' tag there and questions such as this come up from time to time.

Comment: This isn't a genealogy question. Try posting a question to the experts at http://forums.aaca.org/forum/107-pre-wwii-photos/ (Antique Automobile Club of America).

Comment: Personally, I think this question is very on-topic here because it relates to Family History, and the identification of the individual in the car, using the car as part of the process.  I agree that there are other places that would be as or more likely to produce a quicker answer to this one, but providing some of them as comments or answers is the best way to do that.

Comment: This question is totally on topic, because the OP is looking for a clue (age of the car) to help narrow down which possible family member might be in the photo. This is no different from asking about the approx. date of a military uniform, hair style or other garment.

Comment: I see both sides of on and off topic but simply retitling it to date the photo would address it. Car last long than clothing styles and the combination of the too are valid timeframe identifiers. So if it is a date this photo, primarily clues being car and clothing .. maybe just needs to be reworded to reflect that it.

Comment: @CRSouser I've edited the question to make it more on topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The car seems most likely to be an early-1940s model Chevy or Plymouth Coupe.  The third picture is not the same car; it's a 1920s sedan style.  The man's shoes are two-tone style that might be a [Spectator shoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectator_shoe) which apparently had a long fashion run so may not be too helpful.